# equalTo not working firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Here is my realtime db structure

```
myproject
|---------event
              |--date1
                  |--adminid1
                       |-----hallID1
                               |--name:"abc"
                               |--address: "xyz"
             |--date2
                 |--adminid1
                      |-----hallID2
                              |--name:"asd"
                              |--address: "somenadd"
```

I am trying to an autocomplete search box  for `name` element of my json structure, whenever user enters more than three characters in my search box , I call the search() function which queries firebase db as follows:

```
scope.search = function(){
        firebaseDb
        .ref("event")
        .orderByChild("name")
        .startAt(scope.searchBarModel) 
        .endAt(scope.searchBarModel + "\uf8ff")     
        .on("child_added", function(snapshot){
            console(snapshot.key);
        });     
    }
```

However, the above query is not able to find the records in db , what am I doing wrong?

PS: Also same is the case with equalTo query :

```
scope.search = function(){
        firebaseDb
        .ref("event")
        .orderByChild("name")
        .equalTo(scope.searchBarModel) 
        .on("child_added", function(snapshot){
            console(snapshot.key);
        });     
    }
```

Comment: Change "child_added" to value. Child added only fires when someone writes to that area of the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in my comment you just need to change `"child_added"` to `"value"`. The reason for this is because `"child_added"` will only fire when new data is written to that node. Since you want existing data `"value"` is what you want to use. You also might want to use `.once()` instead of `on()` so that the listener is detached. You can read more [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write)